# Ethernaut fallback level 2 not accepting transfers

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to pass level 2 on Ethernaut https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9CB391dbcD447E645D6Cb55dE6ca23164130D008 by calling

```
await contract.sendTransaction({from: player, value: toWei('.0001')})
```

but am getting `Uncaught r: Transaction: 0x77e762fa1b38ed4752aad3d18030bdf5368e49f85dd0a8d1187f614e07f317d3 exited with an error (status 0).`

help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling:

```
await contract.sendTransaction({from: player, value: toWei('.0001')})
```

You're invoking the `receive() external payable` function which has an require statement `require(msg.value > 0 && contributions[msg.sender] > 0);`

You've sucessfully passed the first half, but don't already have a non-zero contribution.

If you look closer at the contract, there's a function `function contribute() public payable` that takes contributions <0.001 ether. Call this function first, then you can safely invoke the previous one.

Comment: thank you! I realized I should've mentioned that I tried calling `await contract.contribute()` and then tried running `(await contract.getContribution()).toString()` but see `0` as well.

Comment: Did you pass a value with that call as well? `await contract.contribute({"value": 10000})`

Comment: I have not only because the function signature is defined as `function contribute() public payable`. Does this mean that all methods of a contract can accept an optional object with a value property that indicates the amount of eth to use?

Comment: Only those methods that are declared payable, others will revert if you try to send eth